# ApplyForce and ApplyLinearImpulse in Box2D is not working

Tags: perl, sdl, box2d, game-physics

I am writing a 2D platformer game in Perl with SDL and Box2D,
the `SetLinearVelocity()` function is working well so I can moving my character to left or right. But when I want to make it jump using `ApplyLinearImpulse()`, it is not working, also the `ApplyForce()` is not working too. The character object just stay there.

my code :

```
if ($key_name=~/w/){  
    $me->ApplyLinearImpulse(Box2D::b2Vec2->new(0,20.0), $me->GetWorldCenter());
    }
```

I also tried adding:

```
$world->step(1.0/60.0,10,10);
```

after it, but stil no response.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

oh I found that it is because I should use GetPosition() rather then GetWorldCenter() and the force need to be much bigger to lift my object!